# Optimize MySQL update statement

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6, update

I have an update query that selects data from a table (HST) and updates it into another table (PCL). The PCL table contains ~30000 rows while the HST table contains about 1.1 million rows. I have multiple (composite) indexes on HST and despite being a large table all queries on it are fairly quick (~2-3 sec). However, when I attempt to select rows from this table and update PCL, it takes 3-4 hours, and in most cases I get "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" errors and I have to keep trying until it works.

```
UPDATE PCL 
SET `T2A` = (SELECT HST.`Date` from `HST` WHERE HST.`SYM`=PCL.INST AND 
HST.`DATE` >=  PCL.Date AND HST.`HP` >= PCL.T2 order by HST.`Date` limit 1)    
WHERE `BS` = 'B' AND `T1A` IS NOT NULL;
```

Is there a way I can rewrite the above query so that it runs faster?

Comment: It would be better to add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` (for both tables).

Comment: PCL has about 30K rows. How many are updated by this statement?

Comment: Thanks ypercubeᵀᴹ. I would say around 70%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about something like

```
UPDATE PCL, ( SELECT PCL.SrNo, MIN(HST.Date) minDate
              FROM PCL, HST 
              WHERE HST.SYM=PCL.INST 
                AND HST.DATE >=  PCL.Date 
                AND HST.HP >= PCL.T2 
                AND PCL.BS = 'B' 
                AND PCL.T1A IS NOT NULL
              GROUP BY PCL.SrNo ) subquery
SET PCL.T2A = subquery.minDate
WHERE PCL.SrNo = subquery.SrNo;
```

Of course, proper indices on both tables is safe.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I should have mentioned that SrNo is primary key in each table but independent of one another.

Comment: @Quark *but independent of one another* no dependence in my query. Only SrNo from PCL is used. Twice...

Comment: @Quark Before running the whole query run the subquery separately and check, that all `PCL.SrNo` which must be updated are selected, and that proper `Date` is selected to each `SrNo`. If everything OK run the whole query. Then try to optimize the subquery itself by creating proper indices if needed - outer UPDATE do not need in optimization.

Comment: Hi Akina, I tried running your query however I get a few syntax errors in phpMyAdmin. An expression was expected. (near (), Unexpected token. (near (), A new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near SELECT), Unexpected token. (near )), Unexpected token. (near subquery), A new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near SET). Can you please advise?

Comment: Thank you very much Akina. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Akina, can you please delete/remove the fiddle. I do not want my DB structure to be up on the internet :-)

Comment: @Quark Comment removed. Fiddle cannot be removed - or I don't know how to. Remember one can find the link via Google cache or similar. Next time create fiddle by yourself - remove unnesessary fields, rename required ones if needed...

Answer (score 0):

Another method to write this kind of query:

```
UPDATE PCL AS p
  JOIN HST AS h
    ON h.SrNo = 
       ( SELECT hi.SrNo
         FROM HST AS hi
         WHERE hi.SYM = p.INST
           AND hi.DATE >=  p.Date 
           AND hi.HP >= p.T2
         ORDER BY hi.Date 
         LIMIT 1 
       )    
SET p.T2A = h.Date 
WHERE p.BS = 'B'
  AND p.T1A IS NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: Thanks ypercube. I cannot join on SrNo as they are not related.

Comment: @Quark And again, you forget to look at tablenames where SrNo was taken from...

Comment: @Quark as Akina points, the join on SrNo is a self-join. Both come from HST.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not very familiar with joins. Thank you very much for your advise.

Comment: Thanks ypercubeᵀᴹ. I get "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" errors while trying to run your query. This appears to be a recurring problem on heavy queries. Is there something that can be done to avoid this error? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome. I hadn't noticed your previous comment, about Lock wait timeouts. This could happen in high load, yes. It would probably be better to post a new question, with more details (how many transactions per second do you have, what type of transactions (simple queries/statements (and if they update/insert/delete lots of rows or one) or complicated stored procedures of multiple statements or a mixture, etc). You could add the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` as well.

Comment: Thanks ypercubeᵀᴹ. I use SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST to determine the processes that are running and try to minimize the load by splitting my queries using WHERE. The suggestions you and Akina gave have helped reduce the time it takes to run the query.